# Spring TC Server Migration from 2.9.2 to 2.9.6 - Property Decoder EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException

Tags: tomcat7

I'm using the following:

- vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.Release that came with Spring
  STS-3.6.0-Release.
- tomcat-7.0.53.B.RELEASE
- Using JDK 1.7.0_51.

I have a web application deployed that uses encrypted passwords by PropertyDecode.  When I start the application, I get the following stack trace:

```
Aug 15, 2014 11:36:07 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: No Spring WebApplicationInitializer types detected on classpath
Aug 15, 2014 11:36:08 AM org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationContext log
INFO: Initializing Spring root WebApplicationContext
Aug 15, 2014 11:36:11 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tc Runtime property decoder using memory-based key
Aug 15, 2014 11:36:11 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.TcDecoder initCiphers
INFO: Adding classpath: C:\Users\a433266\springsource\vfabric-tc-server-developer-2.9.6.RELEASE\tomcat-7.0.53.B.RELEASE/../lib/com.springsource.org.bouncycastle.jce-1.46.0.jar to classloader
Aug 15, 2014 11:36:11 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder <init>
INFO: tcServer Runtime property decoder has been initialized in 82 ms
Aug 15, 2014 11:36:11 AM com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder decodePropertyValue
SEVERE: Unable to decode key:base64
org.jasypt.exceptions.EncryptionOperationNotPossibleException: Encryption raised an exception. A possible cause is you are using strong encryption algorithms and you have not installed the Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in this Java Virtual Machine
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.handleInvalidKeyException(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:999)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEByteEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEByteEncryptor.java:976)
    at org.jasypt.encryption.pbe.StandardPBEStringEncryptor.decrypt(StandardPBEStringEncryptor.java:725)
    at com.springsource.tcserver.security.TcDecoder.decrypt(TcDecoder.java:76)
    at com.springsource.tcserver.security.PropertyDecoder.decodePropertyValue(PropertyDecoder.java:235)
```

Has anyone had this issue before?  Thanks in advance for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Looked the the solution was to update my Java Cryptography Extension (JCE) Unlimited Strength Jurisdiction Policy Files in my JVM.